# NSTextField to uint16_t

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, integer

I have a text field in my iPhone app and I want to convert what the user enters and convert that to a `uint16_t`. How can I do that?

The text box will only be their for entering numbers.

Comment: @WTP, why the edit? Is there something wrong with UInt16? It's defined as an unsigned short, same as uint16_t.

Comment: @Caleb I found that it looked nicer. I was going to edit the tags anyway.

Comment: @WTP, but you've changed the OP's question. Now, they really are the same thing, so from a technical standpoint it doesn't make much difference. But the OP may not realize that they're the same, and was asking for UInt16. I'm not sure your personal tastes should come into play here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
uint16_t integer = (uint16_t)[myTextField.text integerValue];
```

This will take the text field's text, convert it to an integer and cast it to a `uint16_t`. Note that it will not work if the user enters [a value bigger than 65,535](http://xkcd.com/571/) (or less than 0 for that matter).