# arc4random_uniform output issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, random

in iOS Objetive-C I am trying to get the number typed by the user in a text field to set the upper bounder of a random number generation function in C.

```
- (IBAction)pushTheButton2:(id)sender {
    u_int32_t upperBound = (u_int32_t) textField3.text;
    textField4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random_uniform(upperBound)];
}
```

The output is a giant number that makes no sense. To test if function works, if I hardcode the actual upper bound in the arc4random_uniform function, such as arc4random_uniform(5), then it works!

I figured this could be some kind of literal conversion, so I tried to make this work with u_int32_t but still not outputting the right range.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTextField to uint16\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600122/nstextfield-to-uint16-t)

Comment: Others have already given you the full answer. In the future, try debugging the code yourself. Set a breakpoint after assigning upperBound, and examine the value. You should be aware that type casting and type conversion are 2 different things. When you type cast something to another type, it does not convert it, it just "stuffs" the value into the variable of the other type without a compiler warning. You can't type cast an NSString to any integer value. You have to call a conversion method, like intValue or integerValue, as explained by the 2 answers below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To parse **string** to **integer** you should do:

```
NSInteger upperBound = [textfield.text integerValue];
```

Comment: Why down vote? @Fogmeister, in your answer `intValue` returns `int`. Then you assign it to `NSInteger`. My answer is different, `integerValue` returns `NSInteger`. The difference is indeed very slight but in my humble opinion my code is more clean.

Comment: I didn't down vote it. That down vote is nothing to do with me. Unlike the down vote on mine which I guess is from you. Lol

Answer (score 0):

You are currently taking the memory reference pointer of the text and using that as the upper bound.

Try doing something like this instead...

```
NSInteger upperBound = [textfield.text intValue];
```

This will convert the string into an int that you can then use in the arc random function.